# Keep running a python script on AWS EC2 even if CLI session is closed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

so I have a script running on (script is inside the instance) my AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu), which should write some results of benchmarks into a txt file (also in the instance itself) every few hours...Now I have run the session with my terminal and ssh, but if I close my terminal or shut down my computer, the script obviously crashes.
I have even tried: "nohup myscript.py &", but without any success.

Would really appreciate some help here

Comment: You expect your script to run when you shutdown the computer? What do you mean by `without any success`?

Comment: Yeah, because the script runs inside the AWC EC2 instance (I have uploaded it into it and started it also inside the instance). I mean that after closing my terminal and starting the session again, the output txt-file was empty..

Comment: You should be aware that you don't need to SSH (or RDP) into EC2 instances to run scripts any more. You can simply invoke scripts remotely using EC2 Systems Manager Run Command. You can use this to easily invoke scripts on one or more EC2 instances identified by instance ID or by tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion the easiest way is to install one of existing [terminal multiplexers](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_termmux.php) like [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) and run your script inside this multiplexer. This will allow your script to run even after disconnecting from shell session.

Please keep in mind that shutting down AWS EC2 machine also kills screen/tmux session and your script won't be restored after starting that machine again. However after detaching from screen/tmux session on remote machine you can safely close or restart your local computer, reconnect after several hours or days or even years and your remote session with your script inside should still exist (as long as AWS EC2 machine wasn't restarted or your screen/tmux session wasn't closed manually be administrator for example).

Comment: So even if the script is running inside the AWS EC2 instance, shutting my local machine down will kill the script inside the EC2 instance?

Comment: No, the local machine will have no effect on a detached screen session on the remote.

Comment: @usdq777: I have updated my answer to make info about restarting less confusing.

Answer (score 41):

Like mentioned above, start a tmux window like on your Amazon ec2 instance:

```
tmux new -s mywindow
```

Once the new window starts, run your script. Once the script is running, you can close your ssh client or shut down your local computer. When you want to see the results, log in to your ec2 through ssh again, and type this:

```
tmux a -t mywindow
```

This would take you back to your original window running your script.

Comment: Thanks, @RRC. This works. Now I have a process running. What happens if I open a new terminal without tmux and close it? I hope the original process will not be terminated too.